# Send a signed integer as a byte via serial in c++ and Arduino read it

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I could send a String via serial, but Arduino reads String very slow. Therefore, I use reading byte in Arduino, but the problem is I don't know how to send a number (<256) as a byte via Serial Port in C++.

Comment: Signed integer upto 255 will require 2 bytes. Firstly define the protocol to be used. For example, you will have to decide whether big endian or little endian will be used.

Comment: Could you put up some sample code up for us?

Comment: So, does your string need reconstructed on Arduino?

Comment: UART is probably the best protocol... And there is a lot of supported libraries for UART communication.

Comment: If you're trying to convert string to char, and send that via serial port, the `String` library supports that.

Comment: Look up converting strings/integers to bytes - this requires the use of bit-wise operations. This may be part of the answer. The other half is if the Arduino board needs to reconstruct the char data type back into strings or integers, or not.

Comment: Tks NonCreature0714, up to now I've not found any way to convert a signed int to a char. Instead of that, I used another way which is may be not faster. That way is stored that int in a string, after that send byte by byte. I hear that using UART is faster than serial port, but I'm not specialized in electrical engineering, so could you give some simple tutorial about that, like connect to Arduino with a PI/computer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the Arduino IDE, under the menu, look at:

`File > Examples > 08.Strings > CharacterAnalysis`

Here I think you'll find something very close what you're looking for. To sum up, it opens a Serial connection (USB) and reads input from the computer. (You'll need to make sure you match the baud rate and use the "send" button.) It's up to you do program the Arduino as you'd like. In the example's case, it simply sends feedback back to the the Serial Monitor. Run it for yourself and see what happens :)

A [MCVE] snippet from the example:

```
void setup() {
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }

    // send an intro:
    Serial.println("send any byte and I'll tell you everything I can about it");
    Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
    // get any incoming bytes:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int thisChar = Serial.read();

        // say what was sent:
        Serial.print("You sent me: \'");
        Serial.write(thisChar);
}
```